# How to handle a ridiculous amount of receiving addresses?

Tags: transactions, wallet, bitcoind, address, receiving

By ridiculous I mean something absolutely absurd. 1 million+ addresses. Like say if Amazon had started to accept payments, how could they possibly keep up? Bitcoind probably can't keep up? How would I go about solving this? How does SatoshiDice or Blockchain deal with this?

Comment: No of bitcoin addresses doesn't matter. Even a simple computer / laptop / smartphone can handle billions of addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's absolutely nothing you need to do per address, so the number of addresses has no effect. You only need to process each transaction.