# Maximum number of transactions in wallet.dat for Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

I know that a large number of key pairs in wallet.dat is not a concern. But is having too many transactions in wallet.dat an issue?

Can Bitcoin Core start crashing after it reaches a certain number of transactions? Say over 100K?

Comment: Check out my answer on a similar question for a previous bitcoin core version: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24947/what-is-the-maximum-of-receive-addresses-the-default-wallet-can-handle/24962#24962

Comment: "how it would affect the wallet if there were transactions linked to each of the 75 million receiving addresses" that is the core of our question.

Comment: Well there is currently a total of ~45,000,000 txs in the blockchain so this is definitely something we can examine on a theoretical basis only.

Answer (score 1):

Large wallets take significantly longer to initialize and eventually bog down the client to the point of making it completely unusable (calls that attempt to sort usable outputs to spend for example get slower). Bitcoin Core's wallet really isn't designed for commercial scale use, but many people have found it usable with half gigabyte wallets (hundreds of thousands of addresses and transactions) or more in this sort of setting.

Once you get beyond the scaling of Bitcoin Core the only other realistic option is moving into a completely custom wallet system, though this has significant risk and cost involved.