# Bitcoin core addresses

Tags: bitcoin-core

How many Bitcoin addresses can Bitcoin Core create? Is there a limit to number of addresses Bitcoin core can crate? Can I use one receiving address for multiple transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How many Bitcoin addresses can Bitcoin Core create?

As many as you want. While the number of addresses possible is finite, it is essentially infinite as the number of possible addresses is extremely massive. There are 2^160 possible P2PKH addresses (1... addresses) and 2^160 P2SH addresses (3... addresses)

> Is there a limit to number of addresses Bitcoin core can crate?

No.

> Can I use one receiving address for multiple transactions?

Yes but that is not recommended. There are enough possible addresses that you can and should always use new addresses.

Comment: I also like this related answer from a few years back, as it discusses performance tests in relation to number of addresses running on bitcoind. 75+ million and no issues. https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/24947/what-is-the-maximum-of-receive-addresses-the-default-wallet-can-handle

Comment: I have paper wallet is okay if I use the same address. Is it possible to create new address for paper wallet beside the on that is given?

Comment: No. A paper wallet is just a private key. Each private key corresponds to only 1 address. If you want a new address, you will need to create a new paper wallet.